# small opensource os for Octeon SoC (MIPS64)

Tags: mips64

I'm looking for a small (<16MB on flash) open source os, preferrably a linux distribution to run on a Cavium Octeon SoC (MIPS64). Hardware also limits me to either run from memory (and preferrably be able to install from there) or use a network installer. Bootloader for the system in question is u-boot and I find it unlikely that it would be wise to attempt to change it.

The only thing I've found that's even close is a limited functionality tor ramdisk (torramdisk) from a few years back, but looks like installation is going to be tough.

I'm trying to not rebuild the wheel here, thanks for your time.